# Enum with raw type cannot have cases with arguments

Tags: ios, swift

```
enum JPEGCompressionLevel: CGFloat {
    typealias RawValue = CGFloat
    case max = 1, high = 0.9, med = 0.5, low = 0.2, custom(CGFloat)
}
```

I get an error for the `custom` case: `Enum with raw type cannot have cases with arguments`

I would like to use the JPEGCompressionLevel with following syntax:

```
let a: JPEGCompressionLevel = .custom(0.3)
let b: JPEGCompressionLevel = .max
print(a.rawValue)
print(b.rawValue)
```

Comment: I think what you're trying to do isn't possible. Or atleast, isn't documented in the Apple docs: https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Enumerations.html. Have you thought about using a struct constant instead of an enum? That way you could simply use any CGFloat, plus the constant defined ones.

Comment: The error means what it says. Associated and raw values are two completely different things.

Comment: @Roberto i have even worse case - string enum contains `case custom1(<another string enum>) case custom2(<another string enum>) ...` and container enum should return value of its current inner enum.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Swift `enum` can have either raw values or associated values, but not both at the same time. In your case, `case max = 1` is a raw value, while `custom(CGFloat)` is an associated value.

To overcome this limit, you could use an `enum` with associated values with a computed property:

```
enum JPEGCompressionLevel {
  case custom(CGFloat)
  case max, high, med, low

  var value: CGFloat {
    switch self {
    case .max:
      return 1.0
    case .high:
      return 0.9
    case .med:
      return 0.5
    case .low:
      return 0.2
    case .custom(let customValue):
      return customValue
    }
  }
}

let a: JPEGCompressionLevel = .custom(0.3)
let b: JPEGCompressionLevel = .max

print(a.value)
print(b.value)
```

For more information, you can refer to this [article](https://medium.com/@PhiJay/why-swift-enums-with-associated-values-cannot-have-a-raw-value-21e41d5ec11).

Comment: it works also with a property `value` renamed to `rawValue` which makes this enumeration to feel like `RawRepresentable`